# change line style with pgfxyline

Tags: tikz-pgf

I use pgfxyline (with and without arrows).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{pgfpicture}{0cm}{0cm}{10cm}{4cm}
    \pgfsetlinewidth{2pt}
    \pgfsetarrowsend{Triangle[scale=1pt]}
    \pgfxyline(3,3)(5,5)
  \end{pgfpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

How can I change the line style (dotted, dashed ...)?

Comment: Adding `\tikzset{dotted}` will probably help.

Comment: The corresponding PGF macro is `\pgfsetdash`.

Comment: how is \pgfsetdash used?

Comment: It is in the manual, bottom of page 1010.

Comment: @Symbol1 Would you like to write up an answer?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I am busy... Would you?